# My pc slows down - freezes occasionaly when I switch accounts

Tags: upgrade

My pc slows down - freezes occasionaly when I switch accounts. This happens only when I switch accounts and not when I boot. The problem occured after the upgrade to ubuntu 17.10. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

maybe when you switch accounts you take the other account open than it Consume more of device resources .
if you want to speed your PC do: LogOut and Login to the other account.